# Hard coded Key storage for encrypted configuration file

Tags: security, encryption

I have developped a software how use an encrypted config file. 
The key is actually hard coded in the C# code.

It's very simple to get the key with a decompiler.

Is there a way to hardened that ?

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the key locally (you don't need to know it, just the instance of the app on the system where the config file lies does) and then use System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData to encrypt the key with a machine or user specific key. Now store that encrypted key on the filesystem.

Comment: May sound odd - then why not encrypt the config file directly using this computed key?

Comment: @mtraut you do, but then you need to protect the key somehow otherwise an attacker can just retrieve the key and read the config anyway. With confidentiality requirements, it's turtles all the way down.

Comment: I don't get the reasoning. I have file X, encrypt it using Y. I have to care about privacy of Y. So i write Y in a file, encrypt using Z. Now i have to care about Z.

Comment: @mtraut except that Z is protected by the operating system's crypto service, so actually Microsoft has to care about Z. Microsoft already _do_ care about Z.

Comment: OK - now i get it. I'm not at home in native MS platforms. You've got an API that derives authentication/authorization from platform logon.

Comment: @mtraut me neither, I'm mainly an iOS/Mac OS guy ;-)